# Sorting complex values in order of ascending imag parts

Tags: python

I have got a list of complex values which comprises of real and imaginary parts.

Is there any possible way I can sort these in order of increasing imaginary values?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [65]: import operator

In [67]: data = [2+3j, 4+5j, 1+2j]

In [69]: sorted(data, key=operator.attrgetter('imag'))
Out[71]: [(1+2j), (2+3j), (4+5j)]
```

---

To plot the points using matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([2+3j, 4+5j, 1+2j])
x, y = data.real, data.imag
plt.scatter(y, x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful. Now is it possible to plot a graph which consists of all imaginary values(on the x-axis) and the real values(on the y-axis). Doing it one by one is very cumbersome.

Comment: This does the job. How to restrict the domain. Say, for imag values, I want to restrict them to -1 to +1 and for real values, there is no restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `values` is the list, this should work:

```
sorted_valued = sorted(values, key = lambda x: x.imag)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful. Now is it possible to plot a graph which consists of all imaginary values(on the x-axis) and the real values(on the y-axis)? Doing it one by one is very cumbersome.